# Can you set the maxlength of a string in WSDL generated by an ASP.Net WebService?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, wsdl, asmx

I am creating a web service in ASP.Net. I have looked and can't find any way of making ASP.Net set the maxLength attribute of string parameters in the generated WSDL file. Is this possible, and if so how can it be done?

Comment: why would you want to do that?? Either you do publish your WSDL - regardless of how big it is - or you don't. Publishing a fragment of a valid WSDL doesn't seem like an awfully good idea...

Comment: I want to do it because the web service is providing an interface to a legacy system with fixed length string parameters, and it would be nice to be able to publish the lengths of the params as part of the WSDL instead of throwing SOAP errors whenever consumers make a mistake.

Comment: If you need this level of control over your WSDL, then you should use WCF and see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554001/how-the-wsdl-is-written-in-wcf/1554037#1554037.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just came across this [old thread](http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/647639-defining-string-parameter-max-length); seems not possible at all