# How the WSDL is written in WCF?

Tags: wcf, wsdl

I want to know how the wsdl is written in wcf.
As i know the proxy class serialize the data and form a soap message to send over network, in the same way , i want to know who writes the wsdl file and takes care of serializing results of a call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The abstract `ServiceHostBase` class has a method called `CreateDescription` that will take your service and operation contracts as well as your fault and data contracts and turns those into a `ServiceDescription`. This is then further handled by a `WsdlExporter` and turned into a WSDL and XSD file. What gets output to the WSDL (and XSD) is available on the service class as the "service description" (property "Description") - it contains information about the endpoints, bindings, other config settings etc.

Have a look at the [MSDN Docs for the WsdlExporter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.wsdlexporter.aspx) class. You can even customize this process, if you want to - see these blog posts for more info on that:

- [Control generated WSDL from WCF Service](http://www.pluralsight.com/community/blogs/kirillg/archive/2006/06/18/28380.aspx)
- [Flattening your WSDL](http://blogs.thinktecture.com/cweyer/archive/2007/05/10/414840.aspx)

And have a look at the MSDN docs on:

- [Metadata Architecture Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730243.aspx)
- [Exporting custom metadata for a WCF extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731213.aspx)

Marc